# Floating button doesn't work when routing to conductor controller a second time

Tags: android, butterknife, conductor

I am using conductor and butterknife.

I have a **BaseController** where I do the BN boilerplate:

```
    protected ButterKnifeController() { }
    protected ButterKnifeController(Bundle args) {
        super(args);
    }

    protected abstract View inflateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @NonNull ViewGroup container);

    @NonNull
    @Override
    protected View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @NonNull ViewGroup container) {
        View view = inflateView(inflater, container);
        unbinder = ButterKnife.bind(this, view);
        onViewBound(view);
        return view;
    }

    protected void onViewBound(@NonNull View view) { }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroyView(@NonNull View view) {
        super.onDestroyView(view);
        unbinder.unbind();
        unbinder = null;
    }
}
```

I have a couple of controllers with FAB in them, although the issue is the same with simple buttons as well.

When I route to a controller for the first time, the onClick() works as expected. But when I route to the controller for the second time the onClick() doesn't.

Here is an example of 2 controllers the first is the one I want to route back to:

**WelcomeController** - Fab works fine when I first route here

```
public class WelcomeController extends BaseController {
    @BindView(R.id.tv_step_title)
    TextView title;

    @BindView(R.id.tv_step_message)
    TextView message;


    @Override
    protected View inflateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @NonNull ViewGroup container) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.controller_base_title_text, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onViewBound(@NonNull View view) {
        super.onViewBound(view);
        title.setText(getResources().getText(R.string.wizard_welcome_step_title));
        message.setText(getResources().getText(R.string.wizard_welcome_step_message));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onAttach(@NonNull View view) {
        super.onAttach(view);
        requestVideoPermissions();
    }

    @OnClick(R.id.fab_next)
    public void onFabNextClick(){
        getRouter().pushController(RouterTransaction.with(new DiagnosePulseController())
                .pushChangeHandler(new FadeChangeHandler())
                .popChangeHandler(new FadeChangeHandler()));
    }
}
```

**SecondController** - Clicking on allDone Fab routes to WelcomeController but no onClick() events fire.

```
public class RecordFingertPulseController extends BaseController {

    private static final String TAG = RecordFingertPulseController.class.getSimpleName();
    public static final String WRIST_PPG_KEY = "wrist_ppg";
    public static final String WRIST_TS_KEY = "wrist_ts";

    private CameraController mCameraController;
    private static final PpgRecordedRxModel PPG_RX_MODEL = PpgRecordedRxModel.getInstance();
    private PulseModel mPulseModel = null;
    private final CameraController.Callback mRxCameraControllerCallback = new CameraController.Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onCameraAccessException() {
            Log.e(TAG, "CameraAccessException");
        }

        @Override
        public void onCameraOpenException(@Nullable OpenCameraException.Reason reason) {
            Log.e(TAG, new OpenCameraException(reason).getMessage());
        }

        @Override
        public void onException(Throwable throwable) {
            Log.e(TAG, throwable.getMessage());
        }
    };

    @BindView(R.id.fab_record_pulse)
    FloatingActionButton mFabRecordPulse;

    @BindView(R.id.fab_all_done)
    FloatingActionButton mFabAllDone;

    @BindView(R.id.tv_step_title)
    MyTextView tv_title;

    @BindView(R.id.tv_step_message)
    MyTextView tv_message;

    public RecordFingertPulseController(Bundle dataBundle) {
        super(dataBundle);
    }

    @Override
    protected View inflateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @NonNull ViewGroup container) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.controller_pulse_recording, container, false);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    protected View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @NonNull ViewGroup container) {
        return super.onCreateView(inflater, container);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onAttach(@NonNull View view) {
        super.onAttach(view);
        setupViews();
        //Analytics screws camera FPS
        FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance(getActivity()).setAnalyticsCollectionEnabled(false);
        startCamera();
        mCameraController.getConductorLifecycle().onAttach();
        subscribeToPpgRecorded();
    }

    private void subscribeToPpgRecorded() {
        PPG_RX_MODEL.getPpgObservable()
                .doOnNext(ppg -> Log.d(TAG, "PulseModel before filter :\t"
                        + ppg.getPulseName() + "\nPulseModel wrist ppg size"
                        + ppg.getWrisrPpgList().size()
                        + "\nPulseModel finger ppg size: " + ppg.getFingerPpgList().size()))
                .filter(ppg -> ppg.getWrisrPpgList().size() > 0
                        && ppg.getFingerPpgList().size() > 0)
                .doOnNext(ppg -> Log.d(TAG, "Got PulseModel() after filter with finger ppg size: "
                        + ppg.getFingerPpgList().size() + "\twrist ppg size: "
                        + ppg.getWrisrPpgList().size()))
                .subscribe(ppg -> finalizeWristRecording(ppg));
    }

    private void finalizeWristRecording(PulseModel ppg) {
//        mFabRecordPulse.setEnabled(true);
        mFabAllDone.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        try {
            mPulseModel = ppg.clone();
        } catch (CloneNotSupportedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Log.d(TAG, "Got the ppg with size: " + ppg.getWrisrPpgList().size());
    }

    private void startCamera() {
        CameraManager cameraManager = (CameraManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);
        String cameraId = null;
        CameraCharacteristics characteristics = null;
        Size videoSize = null;
        try {
            cameraId = cameraManager.getCameraIdList()[0];
            characteristics = cameraManager.getCameraCharacteristics(cameraId);
        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        StreamConfigurationMap map = characteristics
                .get(CameraCharacteristics.SCALER_STREAM_CONFIGURATION_MAP);
        if (map == null) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Cannot get available preview/video sizes");
        }
        videoSize = MyUtils.chooseVideoSize(map.getOutputSizes(ImageReader.class));
        mCameraController = new CameraController(getActivity(), mRxCameraControllerCallback,
                cameraManager, cameraId, videoSize, CameraController.PpgSource.FINGER);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDetach(@NonNull View view) {
        mCameraController.getConductorLifecycle().onDetach();
        mCameraController.getCameraClosedObservable().blockingLast();
        super.onDetach(view);
    }

    private void setupViews() {
        mFabAllDone.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        tv_title.setText(R.string.wizard_record_finger_pulse_step_title);
        tv_message.setText(R.string.wizard_record_finger_pulse_step_message);
        mFabAllDone.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_done_all_white_24dp);

    }

    @OnClick(R.id.fab_record_pulse)
    public void onRecordPulseClick(){
        mFabRecordPulse.setEnabled(false);
        mCameraController.recordPulseClick();
    }

    @OnClick(R.id.fab_all_done)
    public void onAllDoneClick(){
        if(mPulseModel.getFingerPpgList().size() > 0 || mPulseModel.getWrisrPpgList().size() > 0){
            PulseFirebaseRepository.getRepoInstance().create(mPulseModel);
            requestVideoPermissions();      
mPulseModel.savePpg();
    getRouter().pushController(RouterTransaction.with(new WelcomeController())
                        .pushChangeHandler(new FadeChangeHandler())
                        .popChangeHandler(new FadeChangeHandler()));


        }else{
            if(null != getActivity()){
                new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
                    .setMessage(R.string.empty_pulse_error)
                    .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null)
                    .show();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I simply can't figure out why. And it feels like a BN issue. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I think you may get more interest and help if you removed a whole bunch of the code that is unrelated to the issue you are asking about. People generally have an easier time with questions that have been reduced to the simplest code that shows the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that your problem is related to how you get back to the WelcomeController. Your current code creates a new WelcomeController when the `onAllDoneClick()` is called. In the end, you have a WelcomeController, covered by a RecordFingerPulseController, covered by another WelcomeController.

You have already setup the back transition in `onFabNextClick()` where you added the `popChangeHandler`.

The easiest way to return is to call `getRouter().popCurrentController();` instead of adding a new WelcomeController on top of the RecordFingerPulseController. This will leave you with just a WelcomeController.

Comment: I understand it is not clear from the code but there are several(lets say N) controllers between RecordFingerPulseController and HomeController. I can't figure out how to pop all of them and get to Home.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the router implementation, you will find that it has a `popToRoot(...)` method. That should remove everything from the back stack. Here is the method and its comment:-

```
/**
     * Pops all {@link Controller}s until only the root is left
     *
     * @return Whether or not any {@link Controller}s were popped in
     * order to get to the root transaction
     */
    @UiThread
    public boolean popToRoot() {
        ThreadUtils.ensureMainThread();

        return popToRoot(null);
    }
```

There are several other ways to solve the problem.

1. If you don't intend to go back through the back stack, you could replace the controller instead of pushing a new one.
2. You could add use tags along with `popToTag(...)` to unwind the stack to the controller you desire.
3. You can get the back stack as a list using `getBackstack()` and then manipulate things using that information.
4. Etc.

Comment: Sorry, none of these work. It seems there is an issue with the way butterknife handles onclick. It doesn't matter which controller I pop to all buttons don't respond to the onclick. Any additional ideas  would be appreciated.

Comment: If your project, or even better a simplified version, is available on GitHub, I'll gladly build it and debug for you.